# Keeping all columns in pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to run a groupby function in pandas. I appreciate that there are already a lot of posts answering this but I can't get any of the answers to work. I have data as follows:

**This is the input**

| index | created_at | full_text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | date time object | lots of text in here |
| 1 | date time object | lots of text in here |

I need to group the data by the created_at column so that text posted on the same date are grouped together and get the size of the group. I need to keep all the other columns.

I have tried various implementations as variations on the code below. I have also tried converting the datetime object to be just the date but that doesn't group the column properly.
just simply trying:

`df_mh.groupby(df_mh['created_at', 'full_text]).size()`

Doesn't group the date properly.

This is my code at the moment:

`df_mh = df_final.loc[df_final['full_text'].str.contains('mental health')]`

`mh_grouped = df_mh.groupby(df_mh.created_at.dt.date, as_index = False)['full_text'].size()`

**This is the output with the current code. So everything works except the full_text column is missing**

| index | created_at | size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-07-12 | 2 |
| 1 | 2020-10-12 | 1 |

So this works but misses off the full_text column.

How can I write it so that all the columns are preserved?

**Edit**
sample data:

{'created_at': Sun Mar 22 04:11:34 +0000 2020, 'full_text': this is the full text of the first post', 'created_at': Sun Mar 22 04:11:34 +0000 2020, 'full_text': this is the full text of the second post', 'created_at': Sun Mar 24 04:11:34 +0000 2020, 'full_text': this is the full text of the third post'}

So my required process is:
convert time stamp to just the day, month and year and aggregate posts so those written on the same day will be grouped and their number counted. I hope that makes sense

Comment: Can you make a meaningful example and make sure that the expected output matches it ?

Comment: Please provide a sample dataset and expected output

Answer (score 0):

Using `transform` on a groupby object will return a table of the same size which you can then set as your new column.

```
df["size"] = df.groupby("created_at").transform("count")
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have tried that and it still misses off the full_text column and gives a bunch of NaN in the size column. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can join the original dataframe to grouped dataframe by `created_at` field. Something like that:

```
df \
    .groupby("created_at", as_index=False) \
    ["full_text"] \
    .size() \
    .merge(df, on="created_at")
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but that doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
df=df.groupby("created_at",as_index=False).size().assign(full_text=df["full_text"])
```

Comment: Thanks but that returns one row of full text and the rest NaN